# UPDATE clause with parameters returns error because of the syntax

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using an UPDATE command to modify a record,inside the query I'm using parameters. I've been using the same command with parameters but this is the only one throwing an error.

This is the method:

```
 void decreaseReward(string rewardid, int rewardAmount)
    {
        ////Connection String//////////
        string connStr = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=scores;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=password;";
        //Connection object
        MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            dbcon.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Message: " + err.Message);
        }

        if (dbcon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            String query = "UPDATE agentrewards SET @rewardid = @rewardid -  @rewardAmount WHERE agentEid =  @EID";
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbcon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EID", EID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rewardid", rewardid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rewardAmount", rewardAmount);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        dbcon.Close();

    }
```

I'm getting the error

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''r1' = 'r1' -  1 WHERE agentEid =  'H262815'' at line 1'.

In this case r1 is the name of the column I want to modify, it can not be fixed because this method is supposed to update different records based on the rewardid parameter.

This is another query in my code and this one works perfectly:

```
UPDATE agents SET agentTokens = agentTokens + @total WHERE agentEid =  @EID
```

Is there any specific syntax to perform the query on the decreaseReward() method?

Comment: `rewardid` is a string type and `rewardAmount` is int type that can't Subtract, what did you want to do?

Comment: What do you expect the result of `"r1" - 1` to be?

Comment: @D-Shih I want to subtract the value of rewardAmount to the value on the column r1 in this case.

Comment: Fixed it temporarily using concatenation in the query `UPDATE agentrewards SET " + rewardid + " = " + rewardid + " - @rewardAmount WHERE agentEid = @EID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use parameters in MySQL queries to specify table or column names; you can only use them to provide values.

In this situation, you'll need to build your query using string concatenation for the column names:

```
var query = $"UPDATE agentrewards SET `{rewardid}` = `{rewardid}` - @rewardAmount WHERE agentEid =  @EID";
```